# Svelte not updating instantiated component when changing props in parent

Tags: svelte

I found that Svelte does not propagate prop changes from parent to child when the component is instanciated via constructor. Please refer to the following example, and the [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/5b2af607164b43df92ff311e1837bc9e?version=3.49.0):

Code for `App.svelte`:

```html
<script>
    import Nested from './Nested.svelte';
    
    // The name will change after 2 seconds
    // only the inline component will be updated, while the instantiated component will not
    let name = 'world';
    setTimeout(() => { name = 'there'; }, 2000);

    // Instantiate a component via constructor
    // This component will NOT be updated when the name changes
    const component = new Nested({
        target: document.body,
        props: { name },
    });
  
    // This workaround seems to work, but it is cumbersome
    // setTimeout(() => { component.$set({ name: 'there' }); }, 2000):
</script>

<!-- This component will update nicely -->
<Nested name="{name}"/>
```

Code for `Nested.svelte`:

```html
<script>
    export let name;
</script>

<h1>Hello {name}!</h1>
```

Is this behavior expected? Is there a better way to update the instantiated component, eg. some constructor option I am missing?

Comment: The more important question is whether you actually have to use the component constructor like that in the first place.

Comment: @H.B. good point, but I am migrating a legacy application piece-by-piece, so this is an intermediate stage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is expected. When you instantiate a component like that, it exists outside the the compiler-provided reactivity scope.

The `$set` function is the intended way to update its properties. If you do not mind a slightly larger compiler output, you can also enable individual property accessors via [`<svelte:options accessors />`](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-svelte-options).

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/c9a6a74a66254a0b8f50b2a61b6b569b?version=3.49.0)